# @Html.Action asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buenas tardes,

Tengo problemas para ir a una vista, llamándola desde otra vista.

Lo hago de la siguiente forma:

Estoy en la vista OlvidoPassword, y en la vista hay un ViewBag.Usuario, lo que hago es preguntar si el ViewBag es null, en caso de serlo lo mando a la vista ValidarUsuario.

```
@model ProyectoDeGrado.Models.Usuarios
@using db= ProyectoDeGrado.Models.Model1
@{ 
  string Usuario = ViewBag.Usuario;
 }
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Usuario))
{
  @Html.Action("ValidarUserName", "Usuarios");
}
else
{
 @*Serie de codigo*@
}
```

Cuando ejecuto, va a la vista que quiero pero el problema es la forma en que la muestra, en la siguiente imagen se ven los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hermano, ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que cuando entra a:

`@Html.Action("ValidarUserName", "Usuarios");`

Estás renderizando esa vista o vista parcial dentro de la que tienes actualmente. Si deseas realizar una redirección debes utilizar `Response.Redirect`, para que quede así:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Usuario))
{
    @{ Response.Redirect("~/Usuarios/OlvidoPassword"); }
}
else
{
    @*Serie de codigo*@
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si bien se resuelve el problema en vez del Html.Action colocar un Redirect...
La recomendacion es utilizar la vista para cuestiones de visualización y el controlador para organizar cuestiones de que se debe hacer en tal o cual caso, o sea la logica del flujo en cuestiones de la accion que se intenta ejecutar

Esto hace que el código  de tu app quede mas legible, mantenible en un futuro no muy lejano. La recomendacion es si en tu vista tiene algun IF para bifurcar la visualizacion, entonces hazlo en el controlador (depende de cada caso en particular, pero generalmente mantener la vista simple ayuda mucho)

Por ejemplo, en este caso el controlador de OlvidoPassword tendria que tener el IF que esta en la vista que haga el redirect o simplemente que presente tal o cual vista.

Pero algo mucho mejor, es que el controlador tenga un atributo de Autorización [[Authorize]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) que verificar el usuario se encuentra validado, aquí directamente ni siquiera deberas preguntar por el usuario, el atributo hará esto por ti, y redireccionará directamente a la pagina de login configurada den ASP.NET (obviamente también se puede modificar esta pagina a la que redirige).
Esto es para ayudarnos a no estar preguntando si existe algun usuario autenticado (la pregunta por el Usuario distinto de null)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia.

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [MSDN Clase AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)